# Growth function differentiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Another model for a growth function for a limited population is given by the Gompertz function, which is a solution to the differential equation

$\frac{dP}{dt} = c \ln\left(\frac{K}{P}\right)$ $P$

where $c$ is a constant and $K$ is the carrying capacity. Answer the following questions.

1. Solve the differential equation with a constant $c = 0.05$, carrying capacity $K = 4000$, and initial population $P_0 = 750$.
   Answer: $P(t) = $
2. With $c = 0.05$, $K = 4000$, and $P_0 = 750$, find $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} P(t)$.
   Limit:

Comment: I found that P=(k/(d*e^(-ct))) but im not sure if that's correct.

Comment: ya i have to find P(t)

Answer (score 1):

We are given:

$$\dfrac{dP}{dt} = c \ln\left(\frac{K}{P}\right)P$$

With a constant $c = 0.05 = \dfrac{1}{20}$, carrying capacity $K = 4000$, and initial population $P_0 = 750$.

This DEQ is separable as:

$$\dfrac{1}{c \ln\left(\frac{K}{P}\right)P}~dP = dt$$

Substituting the constants and integrating yields the following:

$$\int \dfrac{20}{\ln \left(\dfrac{4000}{p}\right) p}~dp = \int dt$$

This gives us:

$$\large P(t) = 4000 e^{e^{-(c-t)/20}}$$

We now solve for the constant, using $P(0)=750$, yielding:

$$P(t) = 125\ 2^{5-4 e^{-\frac{t}{20}}} 3^{e^{-\frac{t}{20}}}$$

Note: If this exact approach is to difficult to follow, use the numeric $c=0.05$ and you will get:

$$\large P(t) = 4000 e^{-1.67398^{e^{-0.05 t}}}$$

The limit is $4000$ since the two exponential terms go to zero, that is $125 \times 2^5$.

Comment: Can you please go through the steps because I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry if I'm asking a lot...

Comment: ohh man thanks a bunch!!